# the decription field in contact should auto populate as shankarcontact1where shankar is accountname

Tags: trigger

```
trigger AccountContact on Contact (before insert) {
 List<Contact> cons=trigger.new;

    for(Contact c:cons){
    Account acc=[select id,Name from Account  WHERE id=:c.Accountid];
        for(integer i=1;i<trigger.new.size();i++){
            c.Description=acc.Name+'-'+'contact'+i;
    }   

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues with your code

1. SOQL is inside for loop.
2. Code is not optimized correctly

   ```
   trigger AccountContact on Contact (before insert) {

   Set<id> accIds = new Set<id>();
   //get All the Account id
   for(Contact c:cons){
   accIds.add(c.AccountId);
   }

   //get Account details
   Map<ID, Account> accountMap = new Map<ID, Account>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account where id in : accIds]);
   Integer i=1;
   //fill the values
   for(Contact c:Trigger.New){

       if(accountMap.get(c.AccountId).Name=='Shankar'){
           c.Description= accountMap.get(c.AccountId).Name +'-'+'contact'+i;
          i++;
       }
     } 

   }
   ```